# SQL Server subquery returns nothing based on another subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, ssrs-2012

I have a 2 subqueries where based on the first subquery, the second subquery's result changes which I don't want to happen.

The 2 queries are the same exactly other than the variable they use for the date.

The first query always works correctly, but the second query seems to be affected sometimes by the first query.

If I have the first query before the second query then they will both return the same date. If I have the second query before the first, then it sometimes returns nothing.

```
declare @curDate date = DATEADD(week,0,'2016/02/01')
declare @shortDate date = DATEADD(week,-2,@curDate)

SELECT -- Select Columns
    quere1.Location,
    quere1.Product,
    quere1.Short,
    MAX( quere1.Date ) [Date],
    MAX( quere1.Volume ) [Volume],
    MAX( quere1.Cost ) [Cost],
    MAX( quere2.Date ) [DateAgo],
    MAX( quere2.Volume ) [VolumeAgo],
    MAX( quere2.Cost ) [CostAgo]
FROM

    (SELECT --subQuery 1
        cst_mac_a.loc [Location],                 --Branch
        cst_mac_a.product [Product],             --Product
        pro_duct.desc4 [Short],
        MAX( cst_mac_a.datecreated ) [Date],  --Date
        MAX( cst_mac_a.ohvol ) [Volume],        --Volume
        MAX( cst_mac_a.ohextcost ) [Cost]     --Cost
    FROM cst_mac as cst_mac_a
        JOIN pro_type ON pro_type.proType = cst_mac_a.proType
        JOIN pro_duct ON pro_duct.proType = cst_mac_a.proType AND pro_duct.product = cst_mac_a.product
    WHERE
        cst_mac_a.protype = 'HW' AND

        cst_mac_a.datecreated in (SELECT MAX( sub.datecreated ) from cst_mac as sub WHERE 
                                    cst_mac_a.product = sub.product AND sub.datecreated <= @curDate) AND

        cst_mac_a.timecreated in (SELECT MAX( sub.timecreated ) from cst_mac as sub WHERE
                                    cst_mac_a.product = sub.product AND sub.datecreated in 
                                                (SELECT MAX( sub2.datecreated ) from cst_mac as sub2 WHERE 
                                                            sub2.datecreated <= @curDate and sub2.product = sub.product)) AND

        cst_mac_a.PROGRESS_RECID in (SELECT MAX( sub.PROGRESS_RECID ) from cst_mac as sub WHERE 
                                    cst_mac_a.product = sub.product AND sub.datecreated in 
                                                (SELECT MAX( sub2.datecreated ) from cst_mac as sub2 WHERE
                                                            sub2.datecreated <= @curDate AND sub2.product = sub.product)) AND

        cst_mac_a.ohvol <> 0 AND
        cst_mac_a.product = 'A4ROUP'
    GROUP BY
        cst_mac_a.loc,
        cst_mac_a.product,
        pro_duct.desc4)
    as quere1

    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT --Basically same code, subquery 2
        cst_mac_a2.loc [Location],                 --Branch
        cst_mac_a2.product [Product],             --Product
        pro_duct.desc4 [Short],
        MAX( cst_mac_a2.datecreated ) [Date],  --Date
        MAX( cst_mac_a2.ohvol ) [Volume],        --Volume
        MAX( cst_mac_a2.ohextcost ) [Cost]     --Cost
    FROM cst_mac as cst_mac_a2
        JOIN pro_type ON pro_type.proType = cst_mac_a2.proType
        JOIN pro_duct ON pro_duct.proType = cst_mac_a2.proType AND pro_duct.product = cst_mac_a2.product
    WHERE
        cst_mac_a2.protype = 'HW' AND

        cst_mac_a2.datecreated in (SELECT MAX( sub3.datecreated ) from cst_mac as sub3 WHERE 
                                    cst_mac_a2.product = sub3.product AND sub3.datecreated <= @shortDate) AND

        cst_mac_a2.timecreated in (SELECT MAX( sub3.timecreated ) from cst_mac as sub3 WHERE
                                    cst_mac_a2.product = sub3.product AND sub3.datecreated in 
                                                (SELECT MAX( sub4.datecreated ) from cst_mac as sub4 WHERE 
                                                            sub4.datecreated <= @shortDate and sub4.product = sub3.product)) AND

        cst_mac_a2.PROGRESS_RECID in (SELECT MAX( sub3.PROGRESS_RECID ) from cst_mac as sub3 WHERE 
                                    cst_mac_a2.product = sub3.product AND sub3.datecreated in 
                                                (SELECT MAX( sub4.datecreated ) from cst_mac as sub4 WHERE
                                                            sub4.datecreated <= @shortDate AND sub4.product = sub3.product)) 
    GROUP BY
        cst_mac_a2.loc,
        cst_mac_a2.product,
        pro_duct.desc4)
    as quere2

    ON quere1.Product = quere2.Product AND quere1.Location = quere2.Location
GROUP BY
    quere1.Location,
    quere1.Product,
    quere1.Short
Order BY
    quere1.Location,
    quere1.Product,
    quere1.Short
```

Sample Output:

```
curDate = Today
shortDate = 2 weeks ago:
Location | Product | Short | Date | Volume | Cost | DateAgo | VolumeAgo | CostAgo
Mill     | A4ROUP  | BN.   | 2/1/2016|40   | 36   |         |           |

curDate = 1 week ago
shortDate = 2 weeks ago
Location | Product | Short | Date | Volume | Cost | DateAgo | VolumeAgo | CostAgo
Mill     | A4ROUP  | BN.   |1/25/2016|27   | 25   |1/18/2016|   29      | 26
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the way LEFT JOIN works.   It gets all rows from the first query, but only gets matching rows (per the JOIN conditions in the ON clause) from the second query.

If you want to always get all rows from both queries, even if there is no matching row in the opposite query, then you need to use a FULL OUTER JOIN.

Comment: If I add the line:
    cst_mac_a.product = 'A4ROUP'
to the where in the first query, it will return a single line(So we don't have to worry about LEFT/JOIN). If I make the first query 0 weeks ago, second query 2 weeks ago, second query returns nothing(Blank). When the first query is -1 weeks ago and second query is 2 weeks ago, the second query returns the correct result, but the first query is 1 week early.

Comment: Without knowing what your data is, I can't have any basis for knowing why you see the results you see.   If my answer doesn't solve your problem, you need to edit your question and add these details:   Sample data, the Results of your current query, the results you are trying to get instead.

Comment: I added some output. It is a weird issue where the second query's output change based on the first, but I know the data is there.

Comment: What is an example of some data from your table that you would expect to see but are not seeing?

Comment: In my sample output, where it shows information for DataAgo, VolumeAgo, and CostAgo is what I want to see. But I only see this data when curDate is 1 week ago(From 2/1/2016), I want to compare current data to data 2 weeks ago. As you can see the data exists there (The data for date 1/18/2016) but the first query where the date is 2/1/2016 messes up the second query which would be 2 weeks ago(Shown be the first example not showing any data). Basically it's not finding data that is shown in this example.